# txt file with braces convert to dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, txt

i have a txt file which i got from zoom api. I want to transform it to a dataframe for later cleaning. But there is a column that comes with curly braces, it doesn't read it like a dictionary

```
open = pd.read_csv("registrados111.txt", sep = " ")
open.columns = ["page_size","total_records","next_page_token","registrants"]
open.head(1)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qgj4t.png)

**strong text**

I want to be able to clean up that smear, but it won't allow me the square brackets. when I select what type is the dataframe I get pandas.core.frame.DataFrame. and when I only select the "registrants" column I get pandas.core.series.Series

I would like to have an idea of how to display that column in several others. Because I have more than 6000 thousand records that appear like this.

The output should be a dataframe like in the image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6emXn.png)

I've thought about using methods like explode or using split to cut it but it doesn't allow me to read the subscripts it generates later.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(union['registrants']).explode('custom_questions').reset_index(drop=True)
```

```
pe= pd.json_normalize(json.loads(ap.explode("custom_questions").to_json(orient="records")))
```

I would really appreciate anyone who could help me or give me a guide.

These are some records that I get from the txt file

300 6139 4D1YdjmRScmpymp "{'id': '6ciHOSm4Rw', 'first_name': 'yumi', 'last_name': 'napanga', 'email': 'yu@hotmail.com', 'address': '', 'city': '', 'country': 'PE', 'zip': '', 'state': '', 'phone': '', 'industry': '', 'org': '', 'job_title': '', 'purchasing_time_frame': '', 'role_in_purchase_process': '', 'no_of_employees': '', 'comments': '', 'custom_questions': [{'title': 'Departamento/ Región', 'value': 'Lima'}, {'title': 'Género', 'value': 'Femenino'}, {'title': 'Edad', 'value': 'De 18 a 35 años'}, {'title': 'Nivel de estudio', 'value': 'Secundaria'}], 'status': 'approved', 'create_time': '2022-11-24T19:57:18Z'}"
300 6139 4D1YdjmRScmpy "{'id': 'DgyhfejIug', 'first_name': 'Artur', 'last_name': '', 'email': 'ads@gmail.com', 'address': '', 'city': '', 'country': 'CL', 'zip': '', 'state': '', 'phone': '', 'industry': '', 'org': '', 'job_title': '', 'purchasing_time_frame': '', 'role_in_purchase_process': '', 'no_of_employees': '', 'comments': '', 'custom_questions': [{'title': 'Departamento/ Región', 'value': 'CL'}, {'title': 'Género', 'value': 'Masculino'}, {'title': 'Edad', 'value': 'De 18 a 35 años'}, {'title': 'Nivel de estudio', 'value': 'Técnico / Superior'}], 'status': 'approved', 'create_time': '2022-11-24T17:22:44Z'}"

Comment: can you share sample content of: `registrados111.txt`. Tbh most likely it's cleaner json, than what you're getting from `pd.read_csv`. I would try just read file with `open()` and do `json.loads` on that...

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick - assuming `df` is your input dataframe:

```py
import json

df["Registrant_formatted"] = df["Registrant"].str.replace("'", "\"").apply(json.loads)
```

Then you can navigate through the json using `str` handler - for example

```py
>>> df["Registrant_formatted"].str["custom_questions"].str[0].str["title"]
0    Departamento/ Región
Name: Registrant_formatted, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
import ast
df['registrants']=df['registrants'].apply(ast.literal_eval)# to avoid getting this error: JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes

df = df.join(pd.json_normalize(df['registrants'])) #normalize registrants column
dfx = pd.json_normalize(df.pop('registrants'),record_path=['custom_questions']).set_index('title').T.reset_index(drop=True) #custom questions column. Convert questions to column.
final = df.drop(['custom_questions'],axis=1).join(dfx)
print(final)
'''
|    |   page_size |   total_records | next_page_token   | id      | first_name   | last_name   | email        | address   | city   | country   | zip   | state   | phone   | industry   | org   | job_title   | purchasing_time_frame   | role_in_purchase_process   | no_of_employees   | comments   | status   | create_time          | Departamento/ Región   | Género    | Edad            | Nivel de estudio   |
|---:|------------:|----------------:|:------------------|:--------|:-------------|:------------|:-------------|:----------|:-------|:----------|:------|:--------|:--------|:-----------|:------|:------------|:------------------------|:---------------------------|:------------------|:-----------|:---------|:---------------------|:-----------------------|:----------|:----------------|:-------------------|
|  0 |         300 |            6139 | 4D1YdjmRScmpymp   | DvJh6zm | Artur        |             | ad@gmail.com |           |        | CL        |       |         |         |            |       |             |                         |                            |                   |            | approved | 2022-11-24T17:22:44Z | Colombia               | Masculino | De 18 a 35 años | Universitario      |
'''
```

Comment: technically - resolution to OP issue is first 3 lines, which we kind of share 1:1. The rest is literally adjustment of what OP already had. Not sure your answer is sufficiently different to constitute separate answer to mine.

Comment: Hello, I do not think so. Imagine that the custom questions field contains 1000 questions, how should you get each one? I don't use any index number, question title etc. in my solution.

Comment: I'm not saying you did it intentionally - what I'm saying is - you did it at all. If you feel my answer requires giving "full output" - you can comment on my post, however I would caution against putting "exact code", and rather answer more focused issue - in this case conversion to `dict` of column values, which is exactly what 3 first lines do.